# DataContext in Style is not available on the DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a userdefined control that I call SegmentView (derived from ContentControl). Additionally I have a SegmentModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. The SegmentModel has a property which is called StatusController and there is a StatusControllerViewModel.

For most of my views I create view models automatically in XAML and they attach themselves to the models. The viewmodel is then automatically set as DataContext of the view.

It all works well, except for the following. The ModelToViewModelConverter creates a viewmodel, attaches the model and then sets the viewmodel as DataContext of the control. This is how it works for several other things.
Additionally in this style, I have a DataTrigger that simply changes the opacity of the DockPanel. The DataContext of the DockPanel is indeed set to an instance of the StatusControllerViewModel, but, the binding in the DataTrigger is not found.

Btw: The StatusController is a property of a larger model, which is not shown here for brevity. That everything should be correct is shown that the DataContext is really set correctly, to the StatusControllerViewModel. But the Binding tells a different story. It seems that it doesn't "see" the DataContext of the DockPanel, but sees the DataContext of the levels that are above.

The model is a property of the StatusControllerViewModel, to access directly the model.

Any thoughts on this?

```
<Style>
    <Style.Resources >
    <converters:ModelToViewModelConverter x:Key="M2VM"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property = "Template" >
        <Setter.Value >
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type views:SegmentView}">

                <DockPanel x:Name= "DOCKER"  DataContext= "{Binding StatusController, Converter={StaticResource M2VM}, ConverterParameter={x:Type cSharp:StatusControllerViewModel}}" >

                    <DockPanel.Style >
                        <Style TargetType= "{x:Type DockPanel}" >
                            <Setter Property= "Background" Value= "{x:Null}" />
                            <Setter Property= "Opacity" Value= "1" />  

                            <Style.Triggers >
                                <DataTrigger  Binding= "{Binding Path=Model.IsProgressRunning, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneWay}" Value= "True" >
                                    <Setter Property= "Opacity" Value= "0.1" />
                                    <Setter Property= "Background" Value= "Black">
                                </ DataTrigger >
                            </ Style.Triggers >
                        </ Style >
                    </ DockPanel.Style >
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You should pretty much never manipulate the DataContext in a ControlTemplate.

Comment: Maybe `relativesource templatedparent` vs `templatebinding` topic is relevant.